# Is Photo compression-ratio for JPEG exports too high?

Tags: photos

Despite selecting the High option when exporting JPEG images from Photo, I am finding the file size at destination is around 3MB - 60% smaller than when I exported the same images from iPhoto with the High option. Image size is unaffected. If Photo is compressing JPEG images more during export than iPhoto, I fear the image quality is also being reduced. Is this correct?

There is a possibility that Photo is actually extra-compressing images at the import stage, not during export. Or both!

Answer (score 1):

You can export unmodified original photos from the Photos.app from File > Export > Export Unmodified Original.

You can also select a higher resolution when exporting from File > Export > Export or <kbd>cmd</kbd> + <kbd>⇧</kbd>+ <kbd>E</kbd>; and select "Maximum" from the drop down menu.
I suspect it is still recompressed, so it is expectable that the image will be smaller.

Also, check [this question](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/188510/how-to-export-photos-from-the-new-photos-app-in-full-quality) and answers.